# Generic Constructor with zero or more arguments in C#

Tags: c#, class, generics

I was wondering what would be the best way (in C#) to combine my two classes below (so that I can choose either to specify a type or not, in the case when one isn't necessary)?  Also what would be the recommended method for coding MyClass to take in more arguments if necessary? Thanks!

```
public class MyClass{

    public MyClass() {}
}

public class MyClass<T> {

    T myvariable;   

    public MyClass<T>(T arg){       
        myvariable = arg;
    }

    // how can I handle MyClass(arg1, arg2, ....?
    // would I need to create classes MyClass<T,U,...> for each number of argument?
}
```

so that I can delcare MyClass with either...

```
MyClass my1 = new MyClass()
MyClass<string> my2 = new MyClass("test");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so that I can choose either to specify a type or not, in the case when one isn't necessary

Just merge them and create two constructors:

```
class MyClass<T> {

    T myvariable;

    public MyClass(){

    }

    public MyClass(T arg){
        myvariable = arg;
    }
}
```

If you don't need a generic type, use `Void` (**not** `void`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyClass<Void> my1 = new MyClass<Void>();
    final MyClass<String> my2 = new MyClass<String>("Test");
}
```

> coding MyClass to take in more arguments if necessary

If you need a variable number of arguments of same type `T`, use varargs:

```
class MyClass<T> {

    T[] myvariable;

    public MyClass(){

    }

    public MyClass(T... arg){
        myvariable = arg;
    }

}
```

There is no way to declare variable number of heterogenous types like `<T, U, V...>`.

Comment: is there a way to avoid having to force a user to type <Void>, like can it be left out? And would you have any suggestions for more than one argument?  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user1229895: if you simply use `new MyClass()` it will implicitly use `Object` as `T`. Also see my update wrt multiple arguments.

Comment: thanks, I see I must hold it in an array using params (btw, I think thats missing in the signature you wrote?). Much appreciation!

Comment: @user1229895: could you clarify where my mistake is? I wrote `T[] myvariable;` and `T... arg` - it used to compile before posting ;-).

Comment: bit of a mix up I guess ;-), I think someone tagged my post under Java when I should've specified c#....I thought that varargs under c# should include a params keyword

Comment: noticed a slight difference between the implementation given when taken to C#...<System.Void> cannot be passed (in fact crashed my environment), but instead <object> seems to be right. Still wish there was a way to leave the type declaration off when none is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement static factory methods to avoid specifying a type explicitly, e.g.

```
public static MyClass<Void> create() {
    return new MyClass<Void>() 
}
```

and

```
public static <T> MyClass<T> create(T type) {
    return new MyClass<T>(type); 
}
```

Clients can then create new instances like so:

```
MyClass<Void> noType = MyClass.create();
MyClass<String> withType = MyClass.create("some type");
MyClass<Integer> withInt = MyClass.create(123);
```

(provided you have enabled auto-boxing).

Comment: Thanks Erich, am I right in saying that "factories" only call the generic constructor and return an instance?